scipy.ndimage import measurements. how to import 'label'
from pylab import *
from scipy.ndimage import measurements


L = 100
pv = [0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7]
z = rand(L,L)
for i in range(len(pv)):
    p = pv[i]
    m = z<p
    lw, num = measurements.label(m)
    area = measurements.sum(m, lw, index=arange(lw.max() + 1))
    areaImg = area[lw]
    subplot(2,3,i+1)
    tit = 'p='+str(p)
    imshow(areaImg, origin='lower')
    title(tit)
    axis()


I'm trying to run this code in vscode but it is showing this thing on terminal
DeprecationWarning: Please import label from the scipy.ndimage namespace; the scipy.ndimage.measurements namespace is deprecated and will be removed in SciPy 2.0.0.
lw, num = measurements.label(m)
DeprecationWarning: Please import sum from the scipy.ndimage namespace; the scipy.ndimage.measurements namespace is deprecated and will be removed in SciPy 2.0.0.
area = measurements.sum(m, lw, index=arange(lw.max() + 1))
It's supposed to show this
i actually new and dont know how to import label and sum.

According to the error message, you can fix this by changing your import to from scipy.ndimage import label, sum_labels. You would also need to change measurements.label() -> label() and measurements.sum() -> sum_labels() wherever your code uses those functions.

On the second line, instead of from scipy.ndimage import measurements, you can import label and sum with
from scipy.ndimage import label, sum

Then you need to adjust to remove measurements from the rest of your code, like this:
    lw, num = label(m)                             # works when you import label
    area = sum(m, lw, index=arange(lw.max() + 1))  # works when you import sum

